# Vue3 - Call function on a V-for after fetch API

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```js
const responseFromFetch = [{
  name:'apple',
  color: 'green',
},
{
  name:'apple',
  color: 'red',
},
{
  name:'apple',
  color: 'yellow',
},
{
  name:'orange',
  color: 'orange',
},
{
  name:'orange',
  color: 'green',
}]
```

Suppose this data above is the response from a `fetch` call. I want to render it in a list. Instead of:

```js
//apple green
//apple red
//apple yellow
//orange orange
//orange green
```

I want:

```js
 // apple
     //green
     //yellow
     //red
 // orange
     //orange
     //green
```

After the `fetch` call, I:

- sort response alphabetic by name
- get only the names using map
- remove duplicates

Finally, I create a function `getItemPerName` with a `name` parameter, but it returns `undefined` because the `fetch` is not ready, but if I put this function inside the `fetch` call, I can't return the function to put inside the template.

```js
const getItemPerName = (name) => responseFromFetch.filter(item=> item.name == name);
```

My template:

```html
 <div v-for="(name, index) in removeDuplicates">
   <h1>{{ name}}</h1>
   <div v-for="item in getItemPerName(name)" ></div >
 </div>
```

```js
setup() {
    fetchCall.then((response) =>  {
      sort alphabetic response by name
      remove duplicates

     //return cant access getItemPerName If I call the function here because of scope
    })
    const getItemPerName = (name) => responseFromFetch.filter(item=> item.name == name); //undefined because fetch its not ready
    
    onMounted(() => { 
        //return cant access getItemPerName If I call the function here because of scope
    })

    return {
        removeDuplicates,
        getItemPerName //undefined
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a [`reactive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) prop that gets updated inside your `fetch` callback:

```js
import { reactive, onMounted } from "vue"

export default {
  setup() {
    const uniqueItems = reactive({})

    onMounted(async () => {
      const receivedItems = await fetchCall()
      Object.assign(uniqueItems, groupColorsByName(receivedItems))
    })

    return {
      uniqueItems,
    }
  },
}
```

`groupColorsByName()` [reduces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) a given array into a new *object* that maps the item name to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of colors (deduplicated):

```js
const groupColorsByName = (itemsArray) =>
  itemsArray.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c.name] = p[c.name] || {}
    p[c.name].colors = p[c.name].colors || new Set()
    p[c.name].colors.add(c.color)
    return p
  }, {})
```

Then, render that [object with `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object):

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, name) in uniqueItems" :key="name">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <div v-for="color in item.colors" :key="color">{{ color }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-data-with-composition-api-in-vue-3-8fc3f?file=/src/components/Demo.vue)

Comment: Thanks for this solution, really helpful.
I did before with other solution but yours really helped me to achieve want I wanted.